# How to find the Laurent expansion for $\frac{\exp\left(\frac{1}{z^{2}}\right)}{z-1}$ about $z=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I want to find the Laurent expansion for  $\frac{\exp\left(\frac{1}{z^{2}}\right)}{z-1}$ about $z=0$,

I've tried to apply this formula $\frac{1}{1-\omega}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\omega^{n}$ and the usual Taylor series of the exponential function, but I don't know how to continue:
$$\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{1}{z-1}\exp\left(\frac{1}{z^{2}}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{1-z}\exp\left(\frac{1}{z^{2}}\right)\\&=-\left (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }z^{n}  \right )\left ( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!z^{2n}} \right )\end{align}$$
Thanks in advance.
Ps: I tried applying a Cauchy product, but I think this is not appropriate.
Edit 1: If it is useful at the end of the text, the authors say that the Laurent expansion is:
$\sum_{k=-\infty }^{\infty }a_{k}z^{k}$ with $a_{k}=-e$ if $k\geq 0$ and
$a_{k}=-e+1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{(j-1)!}$if $k=-2$ or $k=-2j+1$ where $j=1,2,...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can write two series for $\frac1{z-1}$ in the two regions $|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$ as

$$\frac1{z-1}=\begin{cases}
-\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n&,|z|<1\\\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{-n}&,|z|>1\tag1
\end{cases}$$

---

Second, the Laurent series for $e^{1/z^2}$ for $0<|z|$ is given by

$$e^{1/z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\,z^{-n}\tag2$$

where $a_n$ the sequence such hat

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
1&,n\,\text{even}\\\\
0&,n\,\text{odd}
\end{cases}$$

---

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together reveals

$$\frac{e^{1/z^2}}{z-1}=
\begin{cases}
-\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\,z^{-n}&,0<|z|<1\tag3\\\\
\sum_{m=1}^\infty z^{-m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\,z^{-n}&,1<|z|
\end{cases}
$$

---

---

For $|z|>1$, the Laurent series of $\frac{e^{1/z^2}}{z-1}$ can be written

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{1/z^2}}{z-1}&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty z^{-m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\,z^{-n}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\,\sum_{m=1}^\infty z^{-(n+m)}\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{p=n+m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\sum_{p=n+1}^\infty\,z^{-p}\\\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}  \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\right)\,z^{-p}
\end{align}$$

---

---

For $0<|z|<1$, the Laurent series of $\frac{e^{1/z^2}}{z-1}$ can be written

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{1/z^2}}{z-1}&=-\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\,z^{-n}\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{m-n}\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{p=m-n}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\sum_{p=-n}^\infty z^{p}\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\left(\sum_{p=-n}^{0} z^{p}+\sum_{p=1}^\infty z^{p}\right)\\\\
&=-e \sum_{p=1}^\infty z^{p}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\sum_{p=0}^{n} z^{-p}\\\\
&=-e \sum_{p=1}^\infty z^{p}-\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=p}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!} \right)z^{-p}\\\\
&=-e \sum_{p=0}^\infty z^{p}-\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=p}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!} \right)z^{-p}
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand why took that series for $exp(\frac{1}{z^{2}})$.

Comment: @BrigitteEliana What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand how did you determine that the  Laurent series for $exp(\frac{1}{z^{2}})$ is the given in equation (2)?

Comment: The Laurent expansion for $|z|>0$ of $e^{1/z^2}$ is given by $$e^{1/z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}\,\frac1{z^{2n}}$$Now, note that all of the terms are of even inverse powers of $z$.  That is, all of the coefficients of odd inverse powers are equal to $0$.  So, we define $a_n$ to be $1$ when $n$ is even and $0$ when $n$ is odd.  Then, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}\,\frac1{z^{2n}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n/2)!}\,\frac1{z^n}$.  Is that clear now?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Comment: @BrigitteEliana And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your $=-\left (\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty }z^{m}  \right )\left ( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!z^{2n}} \right )$ changing one of the $n$ to $m$, you can say the coefficient of $z^k$ is

- $-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n!} =-e$ when $k\le 0$
- $-\sum\limits_{n=k/2}^{\infty} \frac1{n!} =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{n=(k-2)/2} \frac1{n!}-e$ when $k\gt 0$ and even
- $-\sum\limits_{n=(k+1)/2}^{\infty} \frac1{n!} =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{(k-1)/2} \frac1{n!}-e$ when $k\gt 0$ and even

But that looks wrong to me:  I do not think $$\cdots -e z^{-5} -e z^{-4} -e z^{-3} -e z^{-2} -e z^{-1} -e z^{0}+ \\(1-e)z^1 +(1-e)z^2 +(2-e)z^3 +(2-e)z^4+\left(\frac52-e\right)z^5+\cdots$$ converges when $|z| \le 1$.

Meanwhile for the same question asked elsewhere, [a suggested answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1226528/6460) was in effect $$z^{-1}+z^{-2}+2 z^{-3}+2 z^{-4}+\frac{5 }{2}z^{-5}+\frac{5}{2}z^{-6}+\cdots$$ but I do not think that converges either when $|z|\le 1$

Comment: The series you wrote for $\frac1{1-z}$ fails to converge for $|z|>1$.

Comment: @MarkViola - You may be correct if you say it fails to converge for $|z|\le 1$

Comment: Henry, $\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ for $|z|<1$, and fails to converge for $|z|\ge 1$.

Comment: @MarkViola I am more worried that $\cdots -e z^{-5} -e z^{-4} -e z^{-3} -e z^{-2} -e z^{-1} -e z^{0}$ does not converge than I am about $(1-e)z^1 +(1-e)z^2 +(2-e)z^3 +(2-e)z^4+(\frac52-e)z^5+\cdots$

Comment: I've posted a complete solution that includes the Laurent series for $|z|>1$ and the Laurent series for $0<|z|<1$.

Comment: @Henry thanks, but there's a little mistake in your answer in the third equation, you should say that k is odd. On the other hand, I don't understand why the series doesn't converge.

Comment: This analysis has several flaws.  First, there are two cases; $(i) \,|z|>1$ and $(ii)\,0<|z|<1$.  Second, for the case $0<|z|<1$, the coefficients of the terms $z^k$, $k\ge 0$ are all equal to $-e$.  Last, the coefficients on the terms $z^k$, $k<0$ are not as given herein.

Comment: @MarkViola Looking at your answer, for $|z|<1$ you have the same answer as mine, but with the sign in the exponent reversed.  This may well be correct as I worry mine does not converge. Thank you.  For $|z|>1$ you seem to have the same answer as the answer as the one I included from the linked question, but I really don't care about that in an expansion about about $z=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Henry

Comment: This answer is wrong.  For $0<|z|<1$, which is the only case you analyzed, the coefficients on $z^k$ are not $-e$ for $k<0$.  And for $k\ge 0$ those coefficients are $0$.